# In Linux, how do I determine optimal value of optmem_max?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming

We have a Linux project where we are pushing struct information over buffers. Recently, we found that the kernel parameter optmem_max was too small. I was asked to increase this by a supervisor. While I understand how to do this, I don't really understand how I know how big to make this.

Further, I don't really get *what* optmem_max is.

Here's what the kernel documentation says:

"Maximum ancillary buffer size allowed per socket. Ancillary data is a sequence of struct cmsghdr structures with appended data."

(I don't really understand what this means in English).

I see many examples on the Internet suggesting that this should be increased for better performance.

In:

> /etc/sysctl.conf

I added this line to fix the problem:

> net.core.optmem_max=1020000

Once this is done, we got better performance.

So to summarize my question:

1. In English, what is optmem_max?
2. Why is it so low by default in most Linux distros if making it bigger improves performance?
3. How does one measure what a good size for this number to be?
4. What are the ramifications of making this really large?
5. Aside from /etc/sysctl.conf, where is this set in the kernel by default? I grepped the kernel, but I could find no trace of the default value of optmem_max being set to 20480 which is the default on our system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. In English, what is optmem_max?

[`optmem_max`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/net.txt) is a kernel option that affects the memory allocated to the [`cmsg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) list maintained by the kernel that contains "extra" packet information like [`SCM_RIGHTS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) or [`IP_TTL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

Increasing this option allows the kernel to allocate more memory as needed for more control messages that need to be sent for each socket connected (including [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) sockets/pipes).

> 2. Why is it so low by default in most Linux distros if making it bigger improves performance?

Most distributions have normal users in mind and most normal users, even if using Linux/Unix as a server, do not have a farm of servers that have fiber channels between them or server processes that don't need GB of IPC transfer.

A 20KB buffer is large enough for "most" that it minimizes the kernel memory required by default and is also easily enough configured that one can do so if they need.

> 3. How does one measure what a good size for this number to be?

Depends on your usage, but the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl) suggests a 64KB size for `optmem_max` and a 16MB size for `rmem_max` and `wmem_max` (which are the send and receive buffers).

> 4. What are the ramifications of making this really large?

More kernel memory that can be allocated to each socket connected, and maybe unnecessarily.

> 5. Aside from /etc/sysctl.conf, where is this set in the kernel by default? I grepped the kernel, but I could find no trace of the default value of optmem_max being set to 20480 which is the default on our system.

I'm not a Linux kernel source aficionado, but it looks like it could be in [`net/core/sock.c:318`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/sock.c#L318).

Hope that can help.